# Logical operators equation in php

Tags: php, logical-operators

i have a problem with my function which should combine logical operators according to data in array:

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(false, "or"),
    1 => array(false, "or"),
    2 => array(true)
);
```

the equation should be:

- false or false or true
- *($arr[0][0] $arr[0][1] $arr[1][0] $arr[1][1] $arr[2][0])*

And the result: true

But something wrong happens in function and it returns false.
What am i missing?

```
var_dump( arrayBoolValidation($arr) );

function arrayBoolValidation (array $arr) {
    $num = count($arr);
    $status = $arr[0][0];
    for($i = 1; $i < $num; ++$i) {
        if ($arr[$i-1][1] == "and") {
            $status = filter_var($status, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) and filter_var($arr[$i][0], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
        } else if ($arr[$i-1][1] == "or") {
            $status = filter_var($status, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) or filter_var($arr[$i][0], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
        }
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Comment: Mikalkenas: Perhaps you should have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Answer (score 2):

It's an operator precedence issue. `and` is not the same as `&&`. Look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

`=` has higher priority than `and`, so `$a = $b and $c;` equals to `$a = $b;`.

You must use extra brackets (`$a = ($b and $c);`) or better use `&&`. Same thing about `or` (use `||`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all conditions have to be evaluated:

Note: I have added the case when no operator is defined.

```
    [...]
    if (!isset($arr[$i-1][1])) {
        $status = $status || $arr[$i][0];  // default: OR, && else
    } else if ($arr[$i-1][1] == "and") {
        $status = $status && $arr[$i][0];
    } else if ($arr[$i-1][1] == "or") {
        $status = $status || $arr[$i][0];
    }
    [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following inside your loop:

```
if ($arr[$i-1][1] == "and") {
    $status = (filter_var($status, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) and filter_var($arr[$i][0], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN));
} else if ($arr[$i-1][1] == "or") {
    $status = (filter_var($status, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) or filter_var($arr[$i][0], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN));
}
```

You'll see the extra brackets.

If you don't put them, you set $status to filter_var($status, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN), which will always be the same as the first entry (false in this case).

Comment: Thanks! didnt know that = has higher priority than and

Answer (score -1):

I think there is something wrong in loop

try,

```
for($i = 1; $i <=$num; ++$i) {
```